# Problem with $PATH variable in terminal in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am using Ubuntu 16.04,  I am facing the problem with conda command (conda: command not found). when I export path of Anaconda3/bin to $PATH conda  command is working. if I open another Terminal and try to use the conda command it's not working (conda: command not found). after the export path each time then only it's working. can anyone help me to fix this error?

Comment: Store the export line into your `.profile` or `.bashrc` or whatever rc file your shell uses. Restart of the terminal might be needed for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change your path, be sure to include the existing part as well. To do that, add $PATH in the new path definition.

```
   export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

Make sure that your /etc/environment is only re-read at reboot.

I think adding the $PATH in your ~/.bashrc can solve your problem.

Comment: thank you @Ronak Khangaonkar it's working

Comment: welcome @RakeshPakide